# Generate a random value in a row based on a value from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, mocking

I want to create a large amount of mock data in a table (in Postgresql). The schema of the table looks like this

```
price     float,
id        id,
period    timestamptz
```

For `price`, this will be a random float number between 1-5

For `id`, this will be a value from another table that contain all value in `id` column (which may have a lot of id)

For `period`, this will generate a random datetime value in a specific range of time.

Here, I want to create a single query that can generate all these rows equal to amount of `id` I have to a specific range of time that I select.

E.g.

Let say I have 3 ids (a,b,c) in another table and I want to generate time series between 2019-08-01 00:00:00+00 and 2019-08-05 00:00:00+00

The result from this query will generate value like this:

```
price      id          period
3.4        b    2019-08-03 10:01:22+00
2.5        a    2019-08-04 05:44:31+00  
4.8        c    2019-08-04 14:51:10+00
```

The price and id are random. Also period, but with specific range. Key thing is that, all ids need to be generated.

Generating random number and datetime is not hard but how can I create a query that can generate rows based on all id gathered from another table.

Ps. I have edited the example which might mislead my question

Answer (score 0):

This answers a reasonable interpretation of the original question.

Getting a random value from a second table can be a little tricky.  If the second table is not too big, then this works:

```
select distinct on (gs.ts) gs.ts, ids.id, cast(random() * 4.1 + 1 as numeric(2, 1))
from generate_series('2019-08-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp, '2019-08-05 00:00:00+00'::timestamp, interval '30 minute') gs(ts) cross join
     ids
order by gs.ts, random()
```

Comment: Your answer will generate all rows from range of specific time with 30 minutes interval. So, it generate a lot of row based on that. But what I asked is just generating x rows that have different id (x is amount of id) with random datetime value in that datetime range.

Comment: @Jamiewp . . . No.  You asked for "For period, this will generate a datetime value based on specific range of time.".  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: Oh sorry, what I meant is to generate random datetime value include in a specific range of time. My example might mislead you. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function make_timestamptz generating a random integer for each part, except year and month. This will create random timestamps. As for getting the id from another table just select from that table.

```
    /* 
     function to generate random integers. (Lots of then needed.)
    */ 
    create or replace function utl_gen_random_integer(
        int1_in integer,
        int2_in integer)
      returns integer 
      language sql volatile strict
      as
    $$
    /* return a random integer between, inclusively, two integers, relative values of the integers does not matter. */
       with ord as ( select greatest(int1_in, int2_in) as hi
                          , least(int1_in, int2_in) as low
                          )
       select floor(random()*(hi-low+1)+l)::integer from ord;
    $$; 

-- create the id source table and populate
create table id_source( id text) ;
insert into id_source( id) 
 with id_range as ( select 'abcdefgh'::text idl)
 select substring(idl,utl_gen_random_integer(1,length(idl)), 1)  
   from id_range, generate_series(1,20) ;
```

And the generation query:

```
select trunc((utl_gen_random_integer(1,4) + (utl_gen_random_integer(0,100))/100.0),2) Price 
     , id
     , make_timestamptz ( 2019                            -- year
                        , 08                              -- month 
                        , utl_gen_random_integer(1,5)     -- day 
                        , utl_gen_random_integer(1,24)-1  -- hours
                        , utl_gen_random_integer(1,60)-1  -- min                  
                        , (utl_gen_random_integer(1,60)-1)::float  -- sec 
                        , '+00'
                        )  

  from id_source;
```

The result generates the time at UTC (+00). However any subsequent Postgres will display the result converted to local time with offset. To view in UCT append "at time zone 'UCT'" to the query.